# Xlib event when window is moved from one workspace to another

Tags: x11, xlib

I want to know the event name of application moving from one workspace to another using Xlib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get a PropertyNotify on _NET_WM_DESKTOP
http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/latest/ar01s05.html#id2568910

(only with WMs that support _NET_WM_DESKTOP, but most standard ones do)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I've a question. When run the application which creates window with XCreateWindow it _NET_WM_DESKTOP occurs why is that for. I guess the first is for setting the window to desktop 0, but why occurs the second one ?

Comment: just depends on how the WM does this. some WMs may not have an optimization to avoid setting it twice to the same value, for example.
Read the WM code and it'll probably be clear.